# Replacing Strings in Oracle 8i Query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle8i

I've got a table like this in ORACLE 8i

```
Value  | Timestamp
KKQ    | 10:00
KVKK   | 11:00
KMPE   | 12:00
PPKKPE | 13:00
```

and I need to replace `KV` for `V`, `KM` for `M`, `PE` for `R` ,`PP` for `N` and `P` for `L` when querying these values.

What's the best way to do it? The problem I see is that we can have ANY combination of the strings in Value column... the values we can have there are: `KK, Q, KV, V, KM, M, PE, R, PP, N, P, L`.

Comment: Could you potentially have values like `KKV` - which should not be modified because it consists of `KK` and `V`, rather than `K` and `KV`?

Comment: Yes. Any combination of the strings I mentioned is possible

Comment: Right, but should that not be modified? Which René's `replace` approach would do?

Comment: If I have PPKM the output should be NM instead of LLM. How can we control if it's PP and not P in the query?

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
  replace(
  replace(
  replace(
  replace(<input>, 
    'KV', 'V'),
    'KM', 'M'),
    'PE', 'R'),
    'PP', 'N')
from
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be solved by SQL, say with several REPLACE functions. The reason for this is that for instance PPP can mean PP-P or P-PP and thus be substituted either by PN or NP. Same for xxxKVxxx; is this KV or is it a trailing K and a leading V?

You will have to write a database function (PL/SQL) that loops through the string and replaces part by part. You will certainly know how to interpret PPP :-)

(BTW: Seems like a bad idea to store the classifications as a concatenated string of letters rather than in a separate table. You are using a relational database system without making use of the relational part. Hence the problem now.)